# I am trying to make 2 person game

Tags: python

Hello I am tryna make 2 person guess the number game but I dont know how to show the win message can someone help?

```
guessp1 = int(input(player1 + "'s turn = "))

if guessp1 > answer:
    print(player1,"has to guess lower!")
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    print(player1,"has to guess higher!")
    time.sleep(2)
guessp2 = int(input(player2 + "'s turn = "))

if guessp2 > answer:
    print(player2,"has to guess lower!")
    time.sleep(2)
else:
     print(player2,"has to guess higher!")
     time.sleep(2)
guessp1 = int(input(player1 + "'s turn = "))

while guessp1 & guessp2 != answer:
    if guessp1 > answer:
        print(player1,"has to guess lower!")
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print(player1,"has to guess higher!")
        time.sleep(2)
    guessp2 = int(input(player2 + "'s turn = "))
    if guessp2 > answer:
        print(player2,"has to guess lower!")
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print(player2,"has to guess higher!")
        time.sleep(2)
    guessp1 = int(input(player1 + "'s turn = "))
```

It always makes the first player winner.

Comment: how do you calculate the score?

Comment: Regardless of the ovwerall logic you most likely need `while guessp1 I= answer & guessp2 != answer:` instead of what you kave now.

Answer (score 0):

This all can be done simpler, if you would learn how to write your own functions, to get rid of repetitive code. Here I make a function, that takes a name of the current player and the answer, inside the function I ask for input and check the answer. If it's correct, `True` is returned from the function, otherwise `False`. Then outside the function you check if the winner is found, and on every step swap players

```
import time
import random

def make_turn_and_check(current_player, answer):
    time.sleep(2)
    guess = int(input(current_player + "'s turn = "))
    if guess > answer:
        print(current_player, "has to guess lower!")
    elif guess < answer:
        print(current_player, "has to guess higher!")
    else:
        return True # winner!
    return False # not winner

answer = random.randint(1,100)
current_player, next_player = 'Bob', 'Alice'

while True:
    # make next player current, and current player next
    current_player, next_player = next_player, current_player
    if make_turn_and_check(current_player, answer):
        break # winner found

print('The winner is', current_player)
```

### Comments:

`while True:` means an infinite loop, it won't stop looping, until you execute `break`.

Syntax `a, b = b, a` means to simultaneously assign `a = b` and `b = a`, but if it would be 2 different lines, for example:

```
a = 'Alice'
b = 'Bob'
a = b
b = a
```

then the result would be wrong, because `a` was already assigned to `Bob` on the first line, so after the second line, both `a` and `b` would be `Bob`. Using syntax `a, b = b, a` the values would be swapped, `b` would be `Alice` and `a` would be `Bob`.

In my code I used it to make the current player out of the next player, and assign the current player to be the next player.

Finally line

```
if make_turn_and_check(current_player, answer):
   break
```

makes a call to the function above, and since the function returns `True` if the winner is found, then in the `if` statement we get to execute line `break`, finishing the game. Otherwise we skip the `break` and go to the next iteration of the loop.

To better understand, you can assign the resulting `True`/`False` value from the function to an intermediate variable:

```
is_current_winner = make_turn_and_check(current_player, answer)
if is_current_winner:
   break
```

`is_current_winner` will be a boolean variable containing `True` or `False`

Comment: can you explain`
```while True:
    # make next player current, and current player next
    current_player, next_player = next_player, current_player
    if make_turn_and_check(current_player, answer):
        break # winner found```

Comment: @nenyox I edited the answer with comments to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep what you have because you wrote it and understand it, just change all your if's and else's for guessp1 and guessp2 to this:

```
if guessp1 == answer:
    print("You win")
    quit()
elif guessp1 > answer:
    print(player1,"has to guess lower!")
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    print(player1,"has to guess higher!")
    time.sleep(2)
```

You might also change your while loop to 'guessp1 or guessp2' instead of 'guessp1 and guessp2'. Good luck!